# WPF ChromiumWebBrowser not initialized while tab is not in view

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I have two tabs, each of which is initialized by a separate context. Both open synchronously, but on the screen at this moment, of course, only one is visible. That tab, which is NOT on the screen, will not start loading the address until it is clearly clicked with the mouse and shown. Are there any ways to make it load in the background?
Thank.

Comment: It's possible, you can either use the [ChromiumWebBrowser Constructor (HwndSource, String, Size)](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser__ctor_2.htm) or call http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_CreateBrowser.htm to force browser creation. If you need an example of getting the HwndSource  see the example in the first API doc link.

Comment: Thanks!! It works, tab is loaded in background but not rendered while click on it. Can you explain how to make browser (or wpf) render it? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What's not rendered when you click on it mean?

Comment: I mean that browser did not draw web site until I opened the tab.

Comment: As you haven't provided an example it's not really possible to say.

Comment: I must warn you about this. I followed the instructions using CreateBrowser and immediately caught a problem with accessing the cookie store. I haven’t figured out how to do it right yet.

Comment: Without an example that reproduces the problem there is nothing I can say really.